# Probability of finding some particle with some energy in a microcanonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics

One considers some microcanonical ensemble with energies in $[E, E + \Delta] \equiv I$ with "small" $\frac{\Delta}{E}$, volume $V$ and $N$ identical particles.

After choosing one particle, the probability $p$ for this particle to have an energy $\epsilon_0 \in I$ is given by

$$ \displaystyle p \equiv p(\epsilon_0) = \sum_{n\, : \, E-\epsilon_0 \leq E_n^{R} \leq E - \epsilon_0 + \Delta} \frac{1}{\Delta \cdot \Omega(E,V,N)} \qquad (\star)$$

where $E_n^{R}$ denotes the energy of the restsystem (containing $N-1$ particles).

Now it should hold that

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{n\, : \, E-\epsilon_0 \leq E_n^{R} \leq E - \epsilon_0 + \Delta} 1 = \Delta \cdot \Omega(E - \epsilon_0, V, N-1)$$

and I am a little bit concerned about this equality since the units don't match up. (Summing up numbers gives some energy?)
Is it possible that one needs to modify eq. $(\star)$ a little bit?

Comment: I think you should just remove the $\Delta$ multiplying $\Omega$?

Comment: Yeah you are right... Seems reasonable now. Thank you.